# Azure functions with Azure Service bus trigger - Metrics for service bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I am using Azure Functions V2 with Azure service bus trigger which is setup to be triggered when there is a message on a ASB subscription. I am trying to see if there is any metrics available on the message receive latency so that i can plot it in my dashboard. I am using ASB standard SKU so when a noisy neighbor issue happens, at least i can identify it as so.

I suspect the code under trigger attribute takes care of retrieving the message. So is there a way i can instrument this to visualize the avg latency? Basically the function provides metrics just for the execution. What i am looking for is end to end latency metrics.

Comment: What latency? Between which points?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using application insights for logging, the function runtime logs a line like below for each message:

```
2019-08-04 21:09:06.026    Trigger Details: MessageId: <Guid>, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTime: 8/4/2019 9:09:05 PM, LockedUntil: 8/4/2019 9:09:35 PM
```

If you parse this log line for the `EnqueuedTime`, and also the logging time (the first timestamp), then we can calculate the send-to-receive latency.

I know this is not the ideal way. I wish function runtime would log events that can easily be looked at in Azure Monitor. Or if it passed in the `EnqueuedTime` with the input trigger, then we can log it ourselves as a custom event in Application Insights.